# HotKey in Visual Studio to arrange the JavaScript code

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

In Visual Studio I arrange the code C# with `Ctrl+K` `Ctrl+D` but JavaScript Code doesn't arrange.

Is there an equivalent key for JavaScript?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio? Javascript syntax formats with `CTRL+K` `CTRL+D` in VS2013.

Comment: @Seany84 VS2010 Professional

Comment: Same key combination in VS2010. Unless your JS code/html is Syntactically correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extension you can download which will do just that:

It has a shortcut key as well.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/41a0cc2f-eefd-4342-9fa9-3626855ca22a